# How many positive integers solutions does $x + y + z + w = 16$ have if $x < y$

Tags: combinations

$x + y + z + w = 16$ is relatively easy, but I'm stuck in the restriction $x < y$.

Comment: When $x+y=2$, we have number of ways for summing $z+w=14$, and that is $\binom{13}{1}$. When $x+y=4$, we have  $\binom{11}{1}$ and so on until when $x+y=14$ and only $z=1,w=1$ works. We sum them all up to get $13+11+9+7+5+3+1=49$. And so the solution is $\binom{15}{3}-49=5*7*13-28=406$. Divide that by 2 to get $203$.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Solution sketch: All the solutions (and you already know how many) are divided into three types: $x<y$, $x = y$ or $x>y$.

The number of solutions with $x = y$, I'm confident you can find.

Exactly half of the remaining solutions have $x<y$.

---

**Edit:** The $x = y$ case.

For this, we are looking for the number of solutions to
$$
2x + z + w = 16
$$
I'm tempted to just to a brute force solution here, as there are so few cases:
$$
\begin{array}{|c|cccccccc|}
\hline x & 1&2&3&4&5&6&7\\
\text{Number of solutions}&13&11&9&7&5&3&1\\
\hline
\end{array}
$$
And the sum of all of these is $7^2 = 49$ (using the well-known fact that the sum of consecutive odd numbers starting at $1$ is a perfect square). But even if you didn't know this, it isn't difficult to add up:
$$
(13+1) + (1+3) + (9+5) + 7 = 14+14+14+7 = 3.5\cdot 14 = 7\cdot 7
$$

Comment: @RenatoBrittoAraujo I added my take on that case (assuming none of the variablees can be $0$).

Answer (score 1):

If $x<y$, then for some positive $k \in \mathbb{Z}$, $x+k=y$. By substitution,

$$2x+k+z+w=16$$